# Call Javascript functions from Server

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2012

I want to develop a simple web part using VS 2012 and add this code for button click:

```
SPListItem Item = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Tasks"].Items.Add();
Item["Title"] = TextBox1.Text;
Item["Due Date"] = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
Item.Update();
Label1.Text = "Item Added";
TextBox1.Text = "";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), 'nima', "alert('this is nima');",true);
```

but the problem is this alert does not show and this code does not render in my page.

How I can inject javascript to a page in Sharepoint 2010?

thanks

Comment: Where did you put the code above? In which event?

Comment: in button click

Answer (score 2):

try once using ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript as below :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "nima", "alert('this is nima');", true);
```

Comment: I test it but does not work

Comment: could u verify if the script is getting on the page via view source.

Comment: No the code isn't on my source

Comment: Your problem seems weird. Then I would suggest u to go for a new webpart to test just RegisterStartupScript method and add it to a new page in SP. It might be a case of conflict somewhere. I have used these methods and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would lean towards throwing the JS into a literal object on the page, as I have found this is 1) easier and 2) give you a wee bit more control on what is really going on. So instead of using the ScriptManager, throw your script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert("this is nima");
});
</script>
```

in a ASP:Literal control.